# Как правильно проводить валидацию сущностей базы данных Spring Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, entity, spring-jpa

Помоги разобраться, как я должен правильно реализовывать взаимодействие с хранимыми в базе данных объектами?

В процессе поиска, как мне кажется я наткнулся на такие рекомендации:

1. Что не стоит использоваться Hibernate Validator для проверки сущностей сохряемых в базу данных. Т.е. для классов которые я помечаю как @Entity.
2. И так же не стоит такие классы привязывать к формам.

Я правильно понимаю, что рекомендуется делать промежуточные классы, например, на каждую форму ввода создавать такого рода классы ProfileForm, RegistrationForm, LoginForm. Где соответственно будут выводиться необходимые поля класса User, а после проведения проверки заполнения полей, надо заполнять объект класса User и его уже записывать с помощьью, например, userRepository.save(user)?

Поясните пожалуйста правильную методику работы с сущностями.

Comment: С такой частой написания тобою вопросов на ruSO, можно будет писать свою книгу по спрингу и хибернету =)

Comment: У меня экспресс курс по Spring. На лету пишу web приложение и познаю))) С утра до вечера занимаюсь)))

Comment: Каждый день у меня возникает проблема с новым вопросом и после нескольких часов поисков ответа я пишу сюда.

Comment: С такими успехами после и сам можешь преподавать. Вспоминается старый анекдот: На семинаре "Как стать миллионером?" ведущий говори: Вас тысяча человек. Билет стоит тысячу. Спасибо, до свидания

Comment: Считатете у меня хорошо получается?)))))

Answer (score 1):

Если мы говорим про обычное web приложение, то ход мыслей правильный. Вам не всегда нужны все поля сущности на форме. Вам иногда нужны поля разных сущностей на форме. Исходя из этого чаще описывают форму как отдельный объект, так называемый Data Transfer Object (DTO), и передача данных от клиента к серверу и обратно происходит посредством этого DTO. Соответственно и валидация данных происходит при помощи DTO. Т.е. валидатор спринга, например, валидирует данные пришедшие в контроллер. Но вот то, что не следует использовать Hibernate Validator я не согласен. Ограничений много не бывает, так что смело развешивайте аннотации по типу `@NotNull` над полями сущностей, и в момент сохранения БД Hibernate еще раз проверит Ваши данные на корректность.

Подытожим:

- Да, Hibernate Validator не стоит использовать для валидации данных с форм.
- Да, не стоит использовать Entity в качестве DTO.
- Валидируйте все, что может сломать Ваше приложение, и желательно не один раз.

Comment: Так к этому я потихоньку пришле. Да у меня Web приложение. А где мне реализовать преобразование моего dto в Entity? Сделать какой-нибудь класс DtoService где будет метод типа DtoToEntity и EntityToDto? Или можно прямо в классе Dto реализовать эти методы? И как лучше реализовывать передачу полей? Через getter и setter или есть какие-то средства, например, видел ModelMapper?

Comment: Бывают mapper-ы, да. Но лично я обычно в dto делаю конструктор, который принимает entity, или набор entity и в конструкторе раскладываю поля. Это когда мы формируем DTO. Когда мы обратно формируем Entity, можно сделать статичный метод внутри entity `fromDTO()`, например, который будет создавать новый объект, наполнять его данными и возвращать.